# Bootstrap 4 Input resize behaviour

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with an input inside a Bootstrap card. I want it to behave as the button on the second card, but somehow it shrinks and stays in-line. I tried adding some `min-width` or fixing its `width` but can't make it work with the responsive behaviour of the button that stacks on top of the other on certain screen width and also shrinks and expands.

[Here](https://bootsnipp.com/fullscreen/aMVjk) is the code on Bootsnipp and a screenshot of the issue:

**Edit:** Adding my code in the post as requested: This is the first card, the one with the input.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/55595c/fff" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">
        <a href="product.html" title="View Product">Product title</a>
      </h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col">
          <select class="form-control btn-block">
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>200</option>
            <option>300</option>
            <option>400</option>
            <option>500</option>
            <option>600</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the real width of the first card? Show your code in question.

Comment: I tried adding `min-width: 100px` to the `select` tag and it worked, can you try that?

Comment: Thank you a lot @IvanS95. That made it.

Comment: Great :) glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the wrapper columns to `col-12` use the 12 available ones, and add some margin bottom to the `select` with `mb-3`. The next code modification should work, i have tested it on your code:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3"> <!-- changes here ... -->
    <select class="form-control btn-block">
      <option>50</option>
      <option>100</option>
      <option>200</option>
      <option>300</option>
      <option>400</option>
      <option>500</option>
      <option>600</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12"> <!-- ... and here -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will make the element use the full width all the time though, so on bigger screens it'll expand too much

Comment: In that case he could use `col-md-6` or in some other breakpoint he would like. The previous one will use `6` columns for **MD** screens and above and `12` columns for lower screen sizes.

Comment: I tested it adding col-md-6 and another breakpoints but i'll stay with your answer. Col-12 looks good for the design. Thanks a lot.